# Windows 10 dragging title bar of maximised window does not work

Tags: windows-10

On Windows 10, you can drag the title bar of a maximised window. For some reason, it does not work any more for any window. I created a new user, and it worked on that account.

I think some setting is set wrong, but I have no recollection of changing that kind of settings. How can I make it work again?

Comment: I have seen changes happen with different updates and my Win 10 has some options that don't even exist anymore that did a couple months ago before an update. It's called a "push" -- an update on the OS itself. Win 10 was pushed out to market too fast with many many bugs. I'd just make sure to do updates. Have you tried right-click, select Move? Or restore-down, option, box first on the window?

Comment: The system menu worked fine; just dragging a maximised window did not. It turned out that it was part of Aero Snapping.

Comment: Ah. Not familiar. I guess you'll create the solution as an answer once the site allows you to do it.

Comment: I'll make an answer to it, giving credit where It goes, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I searched Google and found that there is a registry setting to enable/disable it. However, mine was already set to 1, so it was not the cause. Then I realised I had disabled Aero Snapping in Settings -> System -> Multitasking -> Snap -> Arrange windows automatically by dragging to them sides or corners of the screen.
>
> I had disabled it because the snapping was usually triggered unwantedly when I try to move the window. But it seems that dragging a maximised window is part of the Aero Snapping, and disabling it also turns off dragging maximised windows.
>
> I turned Aero Snapping on, and dragging maximised windows worked again.

by the creator of the question:[Damn Vegetables](https://superuser.com/users/203857/damn-vegitables)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problems too. I had turned on Snap setting: 'Snap Window'.

This disallowed me to drag a maximized window from display 1 to display 2.
Turning off the Snap Window, I couldn't move a maximized window.

It turns out that moving a maximized window works in 'Snap window' mode 'On', when you move that window to the other display **fast**. 
Moving it **slow** makes Windows think you want to snap it to an edge, as if you are parking a car backwards and slow.

Solution to move maximized windows:

1. Keep 'Snap Window' -> On
2. For snapping a maximized window, move your mouse **slow** to the edge of a display
3. For moving a maximized window (to a different display) in 'Snap window' -> On, move the maximized window **fast**

Answer (score 2):

```
1. Control Panel
2. Ease of Access
3. Ease of Access Center
4. Make the mouse easier to use
```

(may need to search control panel for this)
  5. Uncheck the box that says "prevent windows from being automatically arranged when moving to the edge of the screen
   6. hit apply

Answer (score 0):

Download a program called Winaero Tweaker. Install the program. In the left hand column scroll down to behaviour. Highlight "Disable Aero Snap" . In the right column untick "Disable dragging of maximized windows". Then sign out of your account or restart the computer for the changes to take affect.

Winaero has a lot of tweaks and other marvels. Playing with any other setting is done at your own risk. I am not and will not be responsible for any child like curiosity.

In other words, leave everything else alone (unless you know what you are doing - or think you do) but be warned bad things may happen.

Comment: Thanks to the dumb*ss who downvoted this answer that exactly resolves the issue.
The setting can also be found and corrected in the registry at HKEY_USERS\...\Control Panel\Desktop\DragFromMaximize (set it from 0 to 1 to solve the issue)